# Internet Explorer 11 : Memory Leak on blank page?

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks, xhtml

Internet Explorer 11 |
Version: 11.0.9600.17280 |
Update Versions: 11.0.12 (KB2977629)

**HTML page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Method of Testing**

1. Navigate to page
2. Open Developer Tools (F12)
3. Switch to Memory Tab
4. Start Profiling Session
5. Hold down Refresh button on page (F5)
6. Watch the memory climb

[Memory Usage Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hIGz.png)

**Other Details**

I have already disabled all plug-ins

*any other information I should provide?*

**The Questions**

Can anyone confirm if this problem is limited to IE11? Is it a bug or should this be expected? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: nothing wrong on my machine

Comment: @Steve since you don't otherwise state - can I assume you are using the same version as me?

Comment: mine is 17278 . Rest are the same

Comment: I noticed the same issue in Edge. See my response on [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042682/how-can-the-total-memory-usage-of-ms-edge-keep-growing-after-dom-object-are-remo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it is being caused by the IE developer tools themselves in some way. If I don't open the developer tools - the memory doesn't seem to build up.

I still wish I knew more details - I'm going to leave this question open for now, maybe somebody with more knowledge will be able to enlighten me.