# IE 10/11 memory is freed after one minute of waiting

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on app which works generates large amount of data. I'm experiencing "out of memory" errors in IE11. I've checked every line where the problem could be, deleted everything unnecesary at the end of calculations, so only a very few data should remain after the whole process. In the attached graph we can see the increase of memory consumption at the end it decrease a bit, but after cca 1 minut of waiting a large amount of memory is freed. Refresh won't help. It's definitely not caused by my application.

[image: Memory consumption]

Is it possible that garbadge collector starts working after some timeout after my application calculation ends? All hints/advices appreciated.

Comment: this is impossible to troubleshoot without seeing the code that is causing the condition.

Comment: `All hints/advices appreciated`  Advice: show code ;  Hint: Ensure the browser is freed to do garbage collection cleanup ; Use `delete` to forcibly  destroy objects ; Ensure the profiler is not running in the Developer Tools, or that the Dev Tools is not open

Comment: vol7ron: I use `variable = null` to destroy all references to unnecessary data or objects. Does `delete` works different?

Comment: vol7ron & Claies: Tried it without dev tools, still got that error. I know it's hard to advise me something without even seeing the code, but I would have to hire you to check the code, because it's a bigger app with more than just few lines.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this effect a few months ago. And found out that something like this is caused by the developer tools itsself. Please also see this question:

[Internet Explorer 11 : Memory Leak on blank page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390188/internet-explorer-11-memory-leak-on-blank-page)

to check if this could be the problem you have.

Comment: I've just tested it without dev tools and still got out of memory error. So it is not dev tools problem. Thanx for the advise, I've had no idea that dev tools can affect this.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an add-on sucking up your memory.
Go to *Start > All programs > Accessories > System Tools and then find "Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)"*, and click that.
Run your page and see if that helps.  If so, you'll need to enable the add-ons one at a time to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I use IE just for testing, usualy in private mode where all extensions should be disabled, so this is not the case.