# How can the total memory usage of MS edge keep growing after Dom Object are removed?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-management, memory-leaks, microsoft-edge

I have a memory "leak" problem in Microsoft Edge browser.

When I run a memory profiling session and take several snapshots, I see the memory between snapshot being freed. but the total memory consumption keep growing (see image).

[image: memory leak]

The memory difference between snapshots are an iframe being add and then removed from the DOM.

How is this possible ?

Comment: Have you found anything about this? I'm trying to track down the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the Edge memory profiler to try to test memory leaks with an iFrame as well. We found that the **Edge profiler itself leaks memory in the context of adding and removing iFrames**.

When tested with the Windows OS performance monitor, I saw a huge difference in adding and removing iFrames without the Edge profiler on versus with it on. See the following graph from the OS performance monitor. 
[image: graph showing that without the profiler on, adding and removing iFrames in Edge does not leak memory. Doing the same with the profiler on does leak memory]
Without the performance monitor on, I add and remove many iFrames repeatedly-- this graph shows perhaps the add/remove of 50 iFrames. The memory used by Edge stays constant around 400MG used by the process. Then, I open dev tools, turn on the memory profiler, and add and remove about 10 iFrames. We see the memory used by Edge shoots up from about 400MG to over 1000MG in a short amount of time.
As such, I no longer trust this profiler for memory testing.